# How to pass JSON data to database using Django and django-jsonfield

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, jstree

I currently have a template in django with the jsTree plugin working that updates/saves the JSON data when a user interacts with the data provided.

I can't figure out how to save this data into my database for a user so that it will return the same JSON data/changes they've made when they return to this page.

Below is the code I have running in the template. Javascript is included in the same file for ease of viewing at the moment.

```
{% extends "testapp/base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}


<div class="container">


                <div class="row">
                    <h3>demo</h3>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                        <button type="button"  onclick="demo_create();">Create</button>
                        <button type="button"  onclick="demo_rename();">Rename</button>
                        <button type="button"  onclick="demo_delete();">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button"  onclick="save_changes();">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="jstree_demo" class="demo" style="margin-top:1em; min-height:200px;">
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>


<!-- This should probably be moved to another JS file at some point -->
<script>

var testData = ["Child 1", { "id" : "demo_child_1", "text" : "Child 2", "children" : [ { "id" : "demo_child_2", "text" : "One more", "type" : "file" }] }];


function save_changes(){
    var updatedJSON = get_tree();
}

function get_tree(){

    var v = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true})
    var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);

    console.log ("Updated Json:");
    console.log(mytext);
    return mytext;
}

function demo_create() {
    var ref = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    sel = sel[0];
    sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"default"});
    if(sel) {
        ref.edit(sel);
    }
    console.log("Tree created:");
    console.log(testData);
    get_tree();
};
function demo_rename() {
    var ref = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    sel = sel[0];
    ref.edit(sel);

    console.log("Renaming:");
    console.log(testData);
    get_tree();

};
function demo_delete() {
    var ref = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    ref.delete_node(sel);

    console.log("Deleting:");
    console.log(testData);
    get_tree();

};
$(function () {
    var to = false;
    $('#demo_q').keyup(function () {
        if(to) { clearTimeout(to); }
        to = setTimeout(function () {
            var v = $('#demo_q').val();
            $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true).search(v);
        }, 250);
    });


    $('#jstree_demo')
        .jstree({
            "core" : {
                "animation" : 0,
                "check_callback" : true,
                "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
                'data' : testData 
            },

            "plugins" : [ "contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", "wholerow" ]


        });
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I found django-jsonfield which I believe should make this process much simpler 
https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

However, after implementing the model below specified in the documentation, I am unsure of how to pass in the JSON data from the template with views and save it to the database.

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
  json = JSONField()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean passing data as json from template (Client side) to Django view (Server side)?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean :) , sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Do you want ajax or form submit? just do it in standard way and be careful about the crsf: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/

Comment: I wanted to do it with ajax. Could you point me in the right direction for what the "standard way" to do this is? Thanks